# Turn monadic validation into applicative?

Tags: validation, haskell, monads, applicative

I need to validate that numeric input is in a certain range. To this end, I'm using

```hs
ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
ensure p v | p v       = Just v
           | otherwise = Nothing
```

One way to check the upper and lower bound of some value `x :: Int` is via monadic chaining:

```hs
let validated = pure x >>= ensure (>0) >>= ensure (<100)
```

To my understanding, the order of the two validations does not matter; hence, it should be possible to rewrite the above expression in applicative form. How?
I did not manage to do it, but I'm hoping to gain a deeper understanding of applicatives once I do :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `liftA2` to combine two predicates:

```
> import Control.Applicative
> :t liftA2 (&&) (> 0) (< 100)
liftA2 (&&) (> 0) (< 100) :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

This function has the right type to be used with `ensure`:

```
validate :: Num a => a -> Bool
validate f g = ensure (liftA2 (&&) f g)
```

Then

```
> validate (> 0) (< 100) 50
Just 50
> validate (> 0) (< 100) 1000
Nothing
```

Comment: I -1ed because of the lack of explaination of the `(a->)` applicative. While this is certainly a sensible use case for it, it can be very confusing to beginners, especially if the question was asked in the context of the completely different Maybe monad.

Comment: For a list of predicates: `validate ps = ensure (all . sequenceA ps)`

Answer (score 6):

The very subtle thing to note here is that "intuitively" the return value of `ensure` doesn't matter. It only matters whether it's `Just` or `Nothing`. To express that, you might give it a more honest type signature:

```
ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe ()
ensure p v | p v       = Just ()
           | otherwise = Nothing
```

Now, since the return value doesn't matter, you should be safe to ignore it. And so the logic becomes this: call `ensure (>0)` and `ensure (<100)`, then combine them together, ignoring their return values, but preserving their `Maybe` shapes.

To do that, you can indeed use applicative. And the function that you're going to apply will do just what I said above: ignore both return values. The "preserve `Maybe` shapes" part will be handled by the `Applicative` instance transparently. So:

```
let validated = (\_ _ -> x) <$> ensure (>0) x <*> ensure (<100) x
```

See how my applied function ignores both parameters and returns `x` itself?

---

But of course, the type signature of `ensure`, as written in your question, suggests that it may be doing something more than just validation. Of course it really can't when it's completely generic, but it could if it was a bit more concrete:

```
ensure :: (Int -> Bool) -> Int -> Maybe Int
ensure p v | p v       = Just (v + 100)
           | otherwise = Nothing
```

And now the order suddenly matters:

```
pure (-5) >>= ensure (>0) >>= ensure (<100) == Nothing
pure (-5) >>= ensure (<100) >>= ensure (>0) == Just 95
```

---

So the bottom line here is: the purpose of `ensure` is a bit ambiguous. Does it really return `Maybe a`? Then the order might matter. Is the true return type `Maybe ()`? Then you can use `Applicative` and ignore those units.

Comment: Great explanation, I think I get the point. My problem is how to combine the results of individual checks. For the raw predicates, this is clear (just combine Booleans), but the type system cannot guarantee that the `ensure` results are identical. Thus, better to combine the predicates, like effectively in your solution and @chepner's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(this is a completely new version of this answer).</sub>

You have

```
ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
ensure p v | p v       = Just v
           | otherwise = Nothing
```

which is actually

```
ensure :: Alternative m => (a -> Bool) -> a -> m a
ensure p v = if p v then pure v else empty
```

so that

```
validated x  =  pure x >>= ensure (>0) >>= ensure (<100)
  = do
       a <- pure x
       b <- ensure (>0) a
       c <- ensure (<100) b
       pure c
  = do
       b <- ensure (>0) x
       c <- ensure (<100) b
       pure c
```

and if `ensure` were an opaque function we would have to stop here.

But since we know its source we can continue,

```
  = do
       b <- if (>0) x then pure x else empty
       c <- if (<100) b then pure b else empty
       pure c
  = do
       _ <- if (>0) x then pure () else empty
       _ <- if (<100) x then pure () else empty
       pure x
  = do
       if (>0) x then pure () else empty
       if (<100) x then pure () else empty
       pure x

  = guard ((>0) x) >> guard ((<100) x) >> pure x

  = [ x | x > 0, x < 100 ]   -- with MonadComprehensions
```

There's nothing essentially monadic about this computation, no value computed at a previous step is used to calculate the next computational step here, just one computational step calculated from a given value, `x`:

```
  = guard ((>0) x) *> guard ((<100) x) *> pure x

  = liftA2 (\_ _-> x) (guard $ (>0) x) (guard $ (<100) x)

  = when (x>0) (when (x<100) $ pure ()) *> pure x

  = when (and [x>0, x<100]) (pure ()) *> pure x
```

The inferred type of the last expression is `Applicative f => f b, x :: b`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! There are now three ways to approach the same problem, and in the end, all arrive at the same solution, just in slightly different shapes. I appreciate all answers. If I pick the one by @chepner, it is because it's a tad easier to read.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster I think theirs is something completely new... the applicative there is on functions, not on Maybes.

Comment: Yes, but the key point I understand is that the predicates must be combined - either in disguise (turning `Bool` into `Maybe ()`) or directly.

Answer (score 1):

No. The difference between Applicative and Monad, whilst both enforce an order between applications, is that Monad can accept values from other actions in the chain, and Applicative cannot. There is an Applicative instance for Maybe, but it works just like the Maybe Monoid: returns the leftmost `Just` value. In other words, the Applicative instance works with values of `Maybe a`, but not `a -> Maybe a`.